# How to add multiple inputs when having multiple outputs in Testcases to hackerrank problem

Tags: python, input, cpu-word, testcase

My program is a game called 'Hangman' finding a word, which added to the program and choosing a word randomly how can i make this possible to write a test case

```html
so far you got:  h___
Enter your next letter: a
so far you got:  ha__
Enter your next letter: r
so far you got:  har_
Enter your next letter: l
Wrong Try Left:  4
so far you got:  har_
Enter your next letter: e
Wrong Try Left:  3
so far you got:  har_
Enter your next letter: o
Wrong Try Left:  2
so far you got:  har_
Enter your next letter: d
so far you got:  hard
YAY!!! You Win
```

I want to add a test case for whole program at once

Comment: Tests are about reproducibility. One thing you can do is fixing the [`seed`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.seed) when testing, so the program will pick the same series of words. Then you can work out input sequences for testing success, failure, and handling of invalid inputs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to validate a unit test with random values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26091330/how-to-validate-a-unit-test-with-random-values)

Comment: Thank you very much I'll try with this method